# Unable to click on Save and Close label

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please help why not able to click on Save and Close image below?  It shows error, no such element

```
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).Click().Build().Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-ImageStrip-Save_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16']/img")).Click();
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<li tabindex="-1"
title="Save &amp; Close (ALT+S) &#10;&#10;Save and close this Lead."
class="ms-crm-CommandBarItem ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu ms-crm-CommandBar-Button"
id="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.SaveAndClose" style="display: inline-block; white-space: pre-line;"
command="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.SaveAndClosePrimary">
<span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label"
    style="max-width: 200px;">
    <a tabindex="0" class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" onclick="return false">
        <img tabindex="-1"
            class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-SaveAndClose_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16"
            style="vertical-align: top;" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"></img>
        <span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" style="max-width: 150px;"
            command="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.SaveAndClosePrimary"> Save &amp; Close </span>
        <div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> Save and close this Lead. </div>
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: <span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label" >
   <a tabindex="0" class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" onclick="return false">
     <img tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-SaveAndClose_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" 
      src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"></img> 
     <span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" style="max-width: 150px;"
      command="SaveAndClosePrimary"> Save &amp; Close </span>
     <div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> Save and close this Lead. </div>  
  </a>
 </span>

Comment: *** Selenium IDE
   Source:
   <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=img.ms-crm-ImageStrip-SaveAndClose_16.ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16</td>
 <td></td>
   </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webdriver is not able to locate the control using the xpath you have used. Try following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/span/a[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']/span[@command='lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.SaveAndClosePrimary']")).Click();
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: Your code is great to learn, but sorry still not work.  Further help please.

Comment: Non of these works for me...crying
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']/img[@class='ms-crm-ImageStrip-Save_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16']")).Click();
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']/a[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']/span[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu']")).Click();            
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/span/a/span[contains(Text(),'Save & Close')]")).Click();

Comment: Mahipal, please email me at "btcanada2008@yahoo.com"   I'd show you detail of HTML tags.  I tried many way but nothing work.  Please help.

Comment: What error you are getting? Could you share the exception trace?

Comment: Result Message: 
Test method NewUnitTestProject.CheckInteractionStatus.ChangeAndCheckInteractionStatus threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']/span[@command='lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.SaveAndClosePrimary']